# Invalid operands to binary * (have 'char *' and 'int *')

Tags: c, pointers

I know it is simple but i can't point out the error exactly
please help !!!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int b[] = {10,20,30,40,50};
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n" *(b+i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need a comma after the double quotes.

Comment: `printf("%d\n", *(b+i));` note the comma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a comma in your `printf` command

`printf("%d\n", *(b+i));` is the correct way to format the print out.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma between the parameters of your printf call:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int b[] = {10,20,30,40,50};
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", *(b+i)); // added comma
    }
    return 0;
}
```